Awkward Situation at Work - Need Advice on handling my senior who has grudges against me
My workplace offered a program where they sold old laptops at a very low price through a lottery system. There weren't enough laptops for everyone, so it was a lucky draw.
Initially, I wasn't interested in the program and had no plans to enter. However, a senior colleague (let's call him John) approached me. Here's where things get complicated:
John registered for the program himself.
He also approached me suggesting I enter for him, promising to buy the laptop from me at the same discounted price if I won. In a way john wanted to increase his odds of getting selected in the lottery through me.
Here's where I messed up: I hesitantly agreed to John's request without thinking it through clearly. Later, my another close friend approached me with the same request. I agreed fully this time and entered my name in the lottery, agreeing to my close friend that in case I get selected, I would sell the discounted laptop to him. My close friend also registered for the program himself, and wanted increase his chances through me just like John.  The problem is, I didn't tell about this change of heart to John.
Fortunately (or unfortunately) my name got selected in the lottery. As per the plan, I gave the laptop to my friend. The senior does not know about this yet. Later when I met the senior, I lied to him that I have changed my mind and I want to keep the laptop for my own personal use (only me and my friend know the actual truth though). The senior didn't say anything to me immediately then. But later I found out through others that he is not happy about my random change of heart and is holding grudge against me.
In hindsight, I realize that I should have avoided registering with the intention of giving the laptop to someone else. especially considering both my Senior and my friend entered themselves as well to increase their odds.
I am afraid this grudge would spill over to office related work as well since I would frequently need to collaborate with my senior for office work.
How to handle this situation?

Grudges? I see nothing here that suggests he is holding even ine grudge, just that he legitimately feels a bit frustrated at the moment. You would too. That's OK. People usually get over such things if you don't insist on making a big deal out of it; if they don't, talk to your manager.

If he is that petty, they he would be pissed at you for something else anyway.

OP lied to his superior, if he finds out, it wouldn't be petty for him not to trust OP.

Are these retired laptops owned by the company or is this some external agency/benefit?

@cdkMoose The OP said "Senior colleague" .  That does not mean "superior" (as in manager)

Be honest with them and appologize for double booking. It is better than the grief on holding onto a lie. If it was flipped, wouldn't you rather be told the truth quickly?

@PeterM  I misinterpreted the "senior", even then, lying like this to a coworker you need to collaborate with is still a bad way to operate

You shouldn’t have lied but it sounds the individual would have been upset regardless. Seriously stop telling lies to people your a grown adult. I don’t find it petty, if you work for someone to stop trusting that individual professionally if they told a lie to you personally

If I were the senior, "I've changed my mind, I'm going to keep it" would annoy me much more than "I've made a mistake and promised it to someone else". The first says you won't do the right thing and the latter says you can't do the right thing (which is of course only partially true, because you have no reason to choose your friend over the senior).

No, your senior does not have a Grudge against you... You have demonstrated to them you are untrustworthy, unreliable, will not honor your word and will lie about things after the fact to protect yourself
Now - I want to be clear, you could have backed out of the deal, told your senior, they would have still been irritated - afterall they asked you first, you agreed and they would be within their rights to expect you to honor your word.
However, by lying about it after the fact, you have demonstrated to your senior a number of things that will tarnish your reputation.
Think about this:
Lets say there is a critical issue at work, You may or may not have been causally responsible for some or part of the issue - The Seniors are working at 1,000 MPH trying to fix it, they are not at the stage where it would be appropriate to do a post-mortem or look at 'what went wrong' - they just want to fix the issue.
Your Senior now cannot trust you to come to them and say 'I may have screwed up here - here is what I did' - because when it came to the laptop, you lied to their face, to save your own.
And that will belief will taint so many interactions with them.
Your only option is to come clean to them - apologize for breaking your word, say that you asked the internet for advise and they pointed out where you messed up and that you are now actively working on yourself to prevent this behavior in the future

They "have a grudge" because you have actively lied to them. You can't act yourself out of a problem you have behaved yourself into.
Go to the "senior," tell them what happened, apologize, and tell them it won't happen again.  Finally, learn from your mistake and don't do this any more.

At this point, you're not obligated to say anything else to John about the laptop.  It's not directly work related.  You're not there to assuage the emotions of a grown man, and you were well within your right to keep the laptop as he wasn't offering you any payment or other recompense for it.
But DO tell your other friend to keep quiet about the laptop, so things don't get messier.
If John doesn't bring it up, let it go.

Just a small correction,John too agreed to pay me the discounted price, just like my friend did. It's just that I decided to prioritise my friend over senior. Though I get your point that senior shouldn't bring personal grudges in work related collaboration.

He made an offer. You declined the offer. End of discussion. He's entitled to be disappointed. He'll get over it.

@keshlam, sounds more like he accepted the offer and then later declined the offer with a lie.

This particular lie is irrelevant to the workplace situation. He changed his mind, for whatever reason, about selling it. That happens when dealing with private sellers; buyer could have changed their mind too. Potential buyer will get over it.

It's probably too late to fix the situation, but be prepared for some backlash.
You agreed to do something for your senior and then changed your mind. That is awkward but survivable.  In my view, the real problem is that you lied to your senior about the situation.
"The senior does not know about this yet." but it's not entirely unlikely that they will find out.  Depending on the size of the company or department, a random comment to someone else could easily work it's way around to John.  It wouldn't be appropriate for John to hold a work grudge against you for changing your mind, but absolutely fair for John to hold a grudge and treat you different because you lied to him.

Only me and my friend know the actual truth. And it's unlikely it would get out as the senior is my friend's senior too, and my friend would obviously not want to let the cat out of bag as it would cause awkward situation for him as well in front of the same senior. Also why I am I not allowed to change my mind? To him I have told that I am keeping the laptop myself for my own personal use and he should understand my reason right? Especially when I registered with my own name in the list.

Your friend might accidentally say something to another peer who says something to another peer that John overhears.  IMO you shouldn't assume that John will never find out.  You are allowed to change your mind and I said that was awkward but OK.  But you lied about what you actually chose to do.  Lying to your superior is generally a bad idea, it minimally erodes trust.

This particular lie is irrelevant to the workplace situation. He changed his mind, for whatever reason, about selling it. That happens when dealing with private sellers; buyer could have changed their mind too. Potential buyer will get over it.

Everything about this happened at work with fellow employees and as far as I can tell their employer is selling them the laptops, how can it be irrelevant to the workplace?

If I were John, I would get over not getting the laptop, but if I found out you lied to me about it, we have a whole different problem.

Yikes.. this is a fine old pickle you've gotten yourself in. Largely by "not using your words like a grown-up" and with bonus "using your words to tell lies".
At this point in time John's annoyed with you because (from his perspective) you went back on the agreement with him for your own benefit. You might prevaricate that you "hesitantly agreed", but I don't think that's how it played out from what he saw, I think as far as he knew you'd plain old "agreed", and then you've gone back on it - especially since this supposed "change of heart" only seemed to have occurred once you'd actually won the laptop lottery.
Those are not the actions to inspire a sense of reliability or trust, and from John's POV either you can't be trusted to stick to an agreement or you never planned on going through with it in the first place so you look like a untrustworthy colleague at best and bald-faced liar at worst.
Of course the fact that what you actually did was even worse doesn't help matters, and you can't just clear up the confusion by coming clean.
If you had just had the awkward conversation with John before the draw that you'd agreed to help your friend instead you probably would have had a much less annoyed John on your hands but you didn't and now there's no out here that isn't going to harm your standing with John. As I see it you have two options -
Option 1: You go to John, explain that you agreed to help your friend out without thinking and then when he approached you afterwards you panicked and lied. You get to clear your conscience and John may or may not appreciate your retrospective honesty, a lot of decent people would understand that everyone screws up and do things they aren't proud of occasionally and move on. I can't say whether John would feel that way, I don't know him.
Option 2: You keep up the lie and hope that John moves on and never finds out. You think John won't find out about this, and maybe you're right, maybe you're not. IME this sort of thing can end up coming to light when you least expect it - and if you think John's annoyed now, I don't think you want to see how he's going to react if he finds out on his own.
I think in terms of outcome Option 2, where John then finds out someway is clearly your worst case scenario but ultimately it's down to you as to whether you come clean or not and what you can live with.
